# How to apply morphological operations in Python to fill a binary contour that has holes inside?

Tags: python, image-morphology

I have a binary contour image that needs to be filled. I can do this in Python with the cv2 library using the floodfill function

```
cv2.floodFill(image, None, (1,1), 1);
```

But this completely fills contours. This is a problem when I have two overlapping contours, for example in the image below, where the object to fill has a "hole".

Using floodfill, the whole structure gets filled.

How can I only fill the space between the boundaries?

[image: Binary contour image to be filled]

Comment: Fill the inner contour, save, fill the outer contour. Outer minus inner.

Comment: I don't see where your contours are overlapping. Choosing a seed in between the two contours should fill only the space in between.

Comment: @Dschoni Both of these comments work, but none is automatic (I need either information on how many contours, or I need information on the seeding spot to fill the one I need). I thought there might be a way of automatically doing this with morphological operations. Find boundaries, fill inners of bounded objects, only accept two colors that can't be neighbors.

Comment: you could set the seed on the outer contour